# If n is a positive integer that is four digits long and is relatively prime to 100!, why must n be prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

Suppose there is some positive integer *n* that is four digits long and is relatively prime to 100! (meaning *n* and 100! have no common factors other than 1). *n* must be prime, but why?

100! is a composite number, but composite numbers can be relatively prime to other composite numbers, so that can't be the reason *n* is prime. *n* being four digits long and 100! having factors that are all less than four digits must have something to do with it, but I can't wrap my head around the exact reason.

So, why does *n* have to be prime in this situation?

Comment: Assume that $n$ is not prime and contains a prime factor $p > 100$. What can you say about $\frac{n}{p}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: suppose some number $n$ is not prime, but $n$ has no prime factors less than 100. That is, $n$ is the product of at least two prime numbers greater than 100. What's the smallest that $n$ could be?

Comment: Ah ha! If n is composite but has no prime factors less than or equal to 100, the smallest n could be would be five digits, so it must be prime. Thank you!